# NextJS Middleware returning Blank Screen When checking for token

Tags: typescript, next.js, middleware

I am making a Spotify Clone using it's API and using Next JS Middleware to implement the redirect conditions, which are to check  whether the user have a token or not, if not redirect to log in page.

but due to some reason it's returning me blank white screen.

here's the code of `middleware.ts` file

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const token = await getToken({ req: request, secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET });

    const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;

    if (pathname.includes("/api/auth") || token) {
        return NextResponse.next();
    }

    if (!token && pathname !== '/login') {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/login', request.url));
    }
}
```

The folder structure is

[image: Folder Structure]

Kindly help me out. You can refer to the full code here https://github.com/dipesh2508/Vibes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into your middleware, it seems like you are blocking all the JS resources including `_next` folder which is essential to load the application itself.

Please correct your conditions accordingly to that and it will work. For a starter you can use below.

```js
if (!token && pathname !== '/login' && !pathname.includes("/_next/")) {
  return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/login', request.url));
}
```

Beware that you might need to exclude your public assets as well for the same. For ex. `favicon.ico`.

Comment: now the application just keeps on loading

Comment: Just debug for which route its reloading you. As I had applied it and it showed up the page for me.